# C# object that represents TFS service hook events

Tags: c#, azure, tfs, hook, ado

I'm looking for a C# object that matches the sample payload of the build.complete event found at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/service-hooks/events?view=vsts#build.complete.  The reference page recommends a nuget package but I can't find a "BuildCompleteEvent" in it.

I am looking for this object because I have a TFS service hook outputting to an Azure Storage Queue, and when I read that message off the queue in an Azure Function I want to be able to parse the message string as a useful C# object.

Comment: Can't you just take the json from the page and in Visual Studio "Paste Special" -> "Paste Json as classes"?

Answer (score 2):

For "Build completed" event:

```
public class Message
{
    public string text { get; set; }
    public string html { get; set; }
    public string markdown { get; set; }
}

public class DetailedMessage
{
    public string text { get; set; }
    public string html { get; set; }
    public string markdown { get; set; }
}

public class Drop
{
    public string location { get; set; }
    public string type { get; set; }
    public string url { get; set; }
    public string downloadUrl { get; set; }
}

public class Log
{
    public string type { get; set; }
    public string url { get; set; }
    public string downloadUrl { get; set; }
}

public class LastChangedBy
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string displayName { get; set; }
    public string uniqueName { get; set; }
    public string url { get; set; }
    public string imageUrl { get; set; }
}

public class Definition
{
    public int batchSize { get; set; }
    public string triggerType { get; set; }
    public string definitionType { get; set; }
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string url { get; set; }
}

public class Queue
{
    public string queueType { get; set; }
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string url { get; set; }
}

public class RequestedFor
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string displayName { get; set; }
    public string uniqueName { get; set; }
    public string url { get; set; }
    public string imageUrl { get; set; }
}

public class Request
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string url { get; set; }
    public RequestedFor requestedFor { get; set; }
}

public class Resource
{
    public string uri { get; set; }
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string buildNumber { get; set; }
    public string url { get; set; }
    public DateTime startTime { get; set; }
    public DateTime finishTime { get; set; }
    public string reason { get; set; }
    public string status { get; set; }
    public string dropLocation { get; set; }
    public Drop drop { get; set; }
    public Log log { get; set; }
    public string sourceGetVersion { get; set; }
    public LastChangedBy lastChangedBy { get; set; }
    public bool retainIndefinitely { get; set; }
    public bool hasDiagnostics { get; set; }
    public Definition definition { get; set; }
    public Queue queue { get; set; }
    public List<Request> requests { get; set; }
}

public class Collection
{
    public string id { get; set; }
}

public class Account
{
    public string id { get; set; }
}

public class Project
{
    public string id { get; set; }
}

public class ResourceContainers
{
    public Collection collection { get; set; }
    public Account account { get; set; }
    public Project project { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string eventType { get; set; }
    public string publisherId { get; set; }
    public string scope { get; set; }
    public Message message { get; set; }
    public DetailedMessage detailedMessage { get; set; }
    public Resource resource { get; set; }
    public string resourceVersion { get; set; }
    public ResourceContainers resourceContainers { get; set; }
    public DateTime createdDate { get; set; }
}
```